# How to handle the case of no link returned to the to attribute of Link component using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am new to programming. I want to return no link for the default case in `switch` statement below,

```
class ParentComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    get_link = () => {
        const item = this.props.item;
        let link;
        switch (item.type) {
            case 'type_1':
                link = this.get_type1_link();
                break;
            default:
                link = '/'; //here i want to return no link
        }
        return link;
    };

    get_type1_link = () => {
        const item= this.props.item;
        const item_data = this.props.item_data;
        const {item_id} = item_data.attributes;
        const filtered_item_data = item_data && item_data.find(item_data 
        => 
            item.id === item_id);
            if (filtered_item_data) {
                return `/viewer/${item_data_id}`;
            } else {
                return '/';
            }
    };

    render = () => {
        const item = this.props.item;
        return (
            <ListItem
                key={item.id}
                link={this.get_link}
                text={this.get_content}/>
        );
    }
}

class ListItem extends React.PureComponent {
    render = () => {
        return (
            <Link to={props.link()}>
                <li>
                    <div className="text">
                        {props.text}
                    </div>
                </li>
            </Link>
       );
    };
}
```

Here in the `ListItem` component it has each `li` item with a link so if the user clicks the `li` item then it navigates the page to the link received from `props.link` callback function.

From the `props.link` there might be no link returned too. How can i handle this case for Link component where no url returned?

Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: You could return an hash instead of a slash, like `link = '#';`

Comment: or will it be possible to return null for default case and display li item based on props.link returning some value or undefined? or is there a better way to refactor this. thanks.

Comment: In your `ListItem` component, you could render either a `Link` or some other tag (`p`, `span`, `div`) depending on the value returned by `props.link()`. So if the returned value is a link, you render a `Link` with the corresponding `to` property; if no link is present, then you would render the other tag (with no `to` property at all)

Comment: could you add the snippet to the ListItem component that you mentioned. thanks

Comment: Try to return `javascript:void(0)` rather than / which would harm nothing on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your `ListItem` to only render `Link` when you have a valid link. Something like:

```
class ListItem extends React.PureComponent {
  render = () => {
    const link = props.link();
    if (link) {
      // link is valid
      return (
        <Link to={link}>
          <li>
            <div className="text">
              {props.text}
            </div>
          </li>
        </Link>
      );
    } 
    return (
      // no valid link returned
      <div>
        <li>
          <div className="text">
            {props.text}
          </div>
        </li>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

and change the default case of `get_link` function to:

```
default:
  link = null;
```

Additionally, you should render `<li>`s tags within a `<ul>`